# CNG. AES. Incorrectly decrypted(possibly encrypted) file

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

I study CNG API, I try to encrypt a file and then decrypt it. To get the key I use SHA512, for AES encryption, with the following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int blockSize = 64;
    const int buffSize = 512;
    DWORD cbHashObject = 0, cbData = 0, cbKeyObject = 0, cbKeyData = 0, cbBlockLen = 0, cbCipherData = 0, cbPlainData = 0, cbBlob = 0;
    PBYTE pbHashObject = NULL;
    PBYTE pbKeyObject = NULL;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg;
    BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE hHashB;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PBYTE pbHash, pbIV, pbBlob = NULL;
    PBYTE pbPlainData = NULL, pbCipherData = NULL;

    BYTE* password = (BYTE*)"pass";

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    char *buff = new char[buffSize + 1];


    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_SHA512_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR1 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbHashObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR2 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbHashObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHashObject);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptCreateHash(hAlg, &hHashB, pbHashObject, cbHashObject, NULL, 0, 0)))
    {

        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR3 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    ZeroMemory(buff, buffSize + 1);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptHashData(hHashB, (PBYTE)password, strlen((char*)password)*sizeof(BYTE), 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR5 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    cbHashObject = 0, cbData = 0;

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbHashObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR6 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbHash = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHashObject);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptFinishHash(hHashB, pbHash, cbHashObject, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR7 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    char *str_hash = new char[cbHashObject*2+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < cbHashObject;i++)
        sprintf(str_hash+2*i,"%02X",pbHash[i]);

    cout << "PASSWORD SHA512 = " <<str_hash<< endl << endl;

    ZeroMemory(str_hash, cbHashObject);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDestroyHash(hHashB)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR8 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR9 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR10 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbKeyData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR11 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC), 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR12 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR13 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbIV= (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen+1);
    for(int i(0); i < cbBlockLen; i++)
    {
        //pbIV[i]=rand();
        pbIV[i]=0xAA;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < cbBlockLen ;i++)
        sprintf(str_hash+2*i,"%02X",pbIV[i]);

    cout << "\n\nIV = " << str_hash;

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlg, &hKey, pbKeyObject, cbKeyObject, pbHash, cbHashObject, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR14 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptExportKey(hKey,NULL,BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB,NULL,0,&cbBlob,0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR15 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbBlob = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap (), 0, cbBlob);

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptExportKey(hKey,NULL,BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB,pbBlob,cbBlob,&cbBlob,0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR16 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    ifstream f1("..\\1.txt");
    ofstream f2("..\\2.txt", ios_base::trunc);

    pbPlainData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, blockSize + 1);
    ZeroMemory(pbPlainData, blockSize + 1);
    f1.read((char*)pbPlainData, blockSize);

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbPlainData, blockSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, &cbCipherData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR15 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbCipherData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbCipherData + 1);
    ZeroMemory(pbCipherData, cbCipherData + 1);

    do {
        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbPlainData, blockSize, NULL, 0, NULL, (BYTE*)pbCipherData, cbCipherData, &cbData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            qDebug()<<"ERROR17 " << hex << status << " E: " << dwErr;
        }
        f2.write((char*)pbCipherData, cbData);
        f2.flush();
        f1.read((char*)pbPlainData, blockSize);
    } while(!f1.eof());
    f1.close();
    f2.close();

    BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbPlainData);
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbCipherData);
    pbPlainData = NULL;
    pbCipherData = NULL;

    memset(pbIV, 0xAA, cbBlockLen);
    memset(pbKeyObject, 0 , cbKeyObject);


    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptImportKey(hAlg,NULL,BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB,&hKey,pbKeyObject,cbKeyObject,pbBlob,cbBlob,0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR18 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    ifstream f3("..\\2.txt");
    ofstream f4("..\\3.txt", ios_base::trunc);

    pbCipherData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, blockSize + 1);
    ZeroMemory(pbCipherData, blockSize + 1);
    f3.read((char*)pbCipherData, blockSize);

    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbCipherData, blockSize, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &cbPlainData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        qDebug()<<"ERROR19 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }
    pbPlainData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbPlainData);
    ZeroMemory(pbPlainData, cbPlainData);

    do{
        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbCipherData, blockSize, NULL, NULL, 0, (BYTE*)pbPlainData, cbPlainData, &cbData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            qDebug()<<"ERROR20 " << hex << status << " E: " << dwErr;
        }
        f4.write((char*)pbPlainData, cbData);
        f4.flush();
        f3.read((char*)pbCipherData, blockSize);
    }while(!f3.eof());
    f3.close();
    f4.close();
    return a.exec();
}
```

At first thought that the problem was in IV, however I removed it and nothing has changed. Here are examples:

Before encryption(1.txt):

```
1234567890
```

After encryption(2.txt):

```
O“сh4W;H;7Т†Gж
qї
–JmdВу•оё:s±°|kД'y|‰зXgK4ПбЖl©bЪmЗШоЏMfU¶ysr‰Ї[Іґћ·У:RљС
```

After decryption(3.txt):

```
ї
–JmdВу•оё:s_T–їя5rJ™U,ЁМЈ‘µМ­ґВ0уБЉO ‰CifБZDЧЈ)Тў«э"ќкгИу}ШЩєьъ©фb\a[
```

Comment: Anything change if you use binary file access?

Comment: Tried it now, nothing has changed.

Comment: I presume you don't receive any errors? Because you seem to keep progressing through your code *even if* an error occurs.

Comment: Programming is the art of problem decomposition, where are your methods? What did you try to debug your problem?

Comment: There were no obvious errors, you're right. I tried to debug the program with a debugger, but it did not give results, at the return of the BCryptEncrypt function, garbage is written to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm studying it too right now. I'm able to crypt a file, but then I can't decrypt it!

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)

#define STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL         ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000001L)

#define DATA_TO_ENCRYPT  "Test Data"

static const BYTE rgbAES128Key[] =
{
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F
};

int main() {

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE       hAesAlg = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE       hKey = NULL;
    NTSTATUS                status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    DWORD                   cbCipherText = 0,
                            cbPlainText = 0,
                            cbData = 0,
                            cbKeyObject = 0,
                            cbBlockLen = 0,
                            cbBlob = 0;
    PBYTE                   pbCipherText = NULL,
                            pbPlainText = NULL,
                            pbKeyObject = NULL,
                            pbIV = NULL,
                            pbBlob = NULL;
    BOOL                    bResult = FALSE;

    wchar_t default_key[] = L"3igcZhRdWq96m3GUmTAiv9";
    wchar_t* key_str = default_key;

    // Open an algorithm handle.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAesAlg, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider\n", status);
        return 0;
    }

    // Calculate the size of the buffer to hold the KeyObject.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAesAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
        return 0;
    }

    // Allocate the key object on the heap.
    pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
    if (NULL == pbKeyObject)
    {
        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Generate the key from supplied input key bytes.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAesAlg, &hKey, pbKeyObject, cbKeyObject, (PBYTE)rgbAES128Key, sizeof(rgbAES128Key), 0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey\n", status);
        return 0;
    }

    // Save another copy of the key for later.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB, NULL, 0, &cbBlob, 0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptExportKey\n", status);
        return 0;
    }

    // Allocate the buffer to hold the BLOB.
    pbBlob = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlob);
    if (NULL == pbBlob)
    {
        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptExportKey(
        hKey,
        NULL,
        BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB,
        pbBlob,
        cbBlob,
        &cbBlob,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptExportKey\n", status);
        return 0;
    }




    HANDLE hInpFile = CreateFileA("C:\\LOL\\file_1.encrypted", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (hInpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Cannot open input file!\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    HANDLE hOutFile = CreateFileA("C:\\LOL\\file_1_decrypted.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hOutFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Cannot open output file!\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    const size_t chunk_size = 48;
    BYTE chunk[chunk_size] = { 0 };
    DWORD out_len = 0;

    BOOL isFinal = FALSE;
    DWORD readTotalSize = 0;

    DWORD inputSize = GetFileSize(hInpFile, NULL);
    while (bResult = ReadFile(hInpFile, chunk, chunk_size, &out_len, NULL)) {
        if (0 == out_len) {
            break;
        }
        readTotalSize += out_len;
        if (readTotalSize == inputSize) {
            isFinal = TRUE;
            printf("Final chunk set.\n");
        }

        //
        // Get the output buffer size.
        //
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, chunk, chunk_size, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &cbCipherText, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
        {
            wprintf(L"**** 1 Error 0x%x returned by BCryptEncrypt\n", status);
            return 0;
        }

        pbCipherText = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbCipherText);
        if (NULL == pbCipherText)
        {
            wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
            return 0;
        }

        // Use the key to encrypt the plaintext buffer.
        // For block sized messages, block padding will add an extra block.
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, chunk, chunk_size, NULL, NULL, NULL, pbCipherText, cbCipherText, &cbCipherText, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
        {
            wprintf(L"**** 2 Error 0x%x returned by BCryptEncrypt\n", status);
            return 0;
        }

        if (!WriteFile(hOutFile, pbCipherText, cbCipherText, &cbData, NULL)) {
            printf("writing failed!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

The main change is the function name, from `BCryptEncrypt` to `BCryptDerypt`.
Also, the file names.

When I change to Decrypt, Irecieve "

> **** 2 Error" error...

That's strange, because I use the same method, the same key...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem, on the last two lines (206,215) change **BCryptEncrypt** to **BCryptDecrypt**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int blockSize = 64;
    const int buffSize = 512;
    DWORD cbHashObject = 0, cbData = 0, cbKeyObject = 0, cbKeyData = 0, cbBlockLen = 0, cbCipherData = 0, cbPlainData = 0, cbBlob = 0;
    PBYTE pbHashObject = NULL;
    PBYTE pbKeyObject = NULL;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg;
    BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE hHashB;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PBYTE pbHash, pbIV, pbBlob = NULL;
    PBYTE pbPlainData = NULL, pbCipherData = NULL;

    BYTE* password = (BYTE*)"pass";

    char* buff = new char[buffSize + 1];


    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_SHA512_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR1 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbHashObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR2 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbHashObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHashObject);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptCreateHash(hAlg, &hHashB, pbHashObject, cbHashObject, NULL, 0, 0)))
    {

        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR3 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    ZeroMemory(buff, buffSize + 1);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptHashData(hHashB, (PBYTE)password, strlen((char*)password) * sizeof(BYTE), 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR5 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    cbHashObject = 0, cbData = 0;

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbHashObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR6 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbHash = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHashObject);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptFinishHash(hHashB, pbHash, cbHashObject, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR7 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    char* str_hash = new char[cbHashObject * 2 + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < cbHashObject; i++)
        sprintf(str_hash + 2 * i, "%02X", pbHash[i]);

    cout << "PASSWORD SHA512 = " << str_hash << endl << endl;

    ZeroMemory(str_hash, cbHashObject);
    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDestroyHash(hHashB)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR8 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR9 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR10 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject, sizeof(DWORD), &cbKeyData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR11 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC, sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC), 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR12 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR13 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbIV = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen + 1);
    for (int i(0); i < cbBlockLen; i++)
    {
        //pbIV[i]=rand();
        pbIV[i] = 0xAA;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cbBlockLen; i++)
        sprintf(str_hash + 2 * i, "%02X", pbIV[i]);

    std::cout << "\n\nIV = " << str_hash;

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlg, &hKey, pbKeyObject, cbKeyObject, pbHash, cbHashObject, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR14 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB, NULL, 0, &cbBlob, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR15 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbBlob = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlob);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB, pbBlob, cbBlob, &cbBlob, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR16 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    ifstream f1("C:\\LOL\\1.txt");
    ofstream f2("C:\\LOL\\2.txt", ios_base::trunc);

    pbPlainData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, blockSize + 1);
    ZeroMemory(pbPlainData, blockSize + 1);
    f1.read((char*)pbPlainData, blockSize);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbPlainData, blockSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, &cbCipherData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR15 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    pbCipherData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbCipherData + 1);
    ZeroMemory(pbCipherData, cbCipherData + 1);

    do {
        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbPlainData, blockSize, NULL, 0, NULL, (BYTE*)pbCipherData, cbCipherData, &cbData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "ERROR17 " << hex << status << " E: " << dwErr;
        }
        f2.write((char*)pbCipherData, cbData);
        f2.flush();
        f1.read((char*)pbPlainData, blockSize);
    } while (!f1.eof());
    f1.close();
    f2.close();

    BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbPlainData);
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbCipherData);
    pbPlainData = NULL;
    pbCipherData = NULL;

    memset(pbIV, 0xAA, cbBlockLen);
    memset(pbKeyObject, 0, cbKeyObject);


    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptImportKey(hAlg, NULL, BCRYPT_OPAQUE_KEY_BLOB, &hKey, pbKeyObject, cbKeyObject, pbBlob, cbBlob, 0)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR18 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }

    ifstream f3("C:\\LOL\\2.txt");
    ofstream f4("C:\\LOL\\3.txt", ios_base::trunc);

    pbCipherData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, blockSize + 1);
    ZeroMemory(pbCipherData, blockSize + 1);
    f3.read((char*)pbCipherData, blockSize);

    if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbCipherData, blockSize, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &cbPlainData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ERROR19 " << hex << status << " E: " << hex << dwErr;
    }
    pbPlainData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbPlainData);
    ZeroMemory(pbPlainData, cbPlainData);

    do {
        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, (BYTE*)pbCipherData, blockSize, NULL, NULL, 0, (BYTE*)pbPlainData, cbPlainData, &cbData, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "ERROR20 " << hex << status << " E: " << dwErr;
        }
        f4.write((char*)pbPlainData, cbData);
        f4.flush();
        f3.read((char*)pbCipherData, blockSize);
    } while (!f3.eof());
    f3.close();
    f4.close();
    return 0;
}
```